# CSS thru PHP Parser vs. PHP as CSS source

Tags: php, css, .htaccess, php-parser

To have my project respond to certain contexts of content, I want my CSS files to respond respectively instead of setting up additional CSS files (adds to http requests)  or parsing the CSS right inside the respective php script (imho: quite messy).

#### CSS thru PHP parser

Now I could tell the PHP parser via .htaccess to treat css files too.
Disadvantages would be: Overhead of processing several css files in my current project-structure OR breaking structure to activate parsing of CSS files just in one subdirectory.
Either way I simply could do it like so:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php php php4 php3 css
```

#### ... vs. PHP scripts as CSS ressource

Or I could link a php source in the page metadata as css source.
Possible disadvantages: May be some browsers won't accept files with different extensions as CSS ressource...?
Anyways...:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/style/preprocessed.css.php" media="all">
```

What would you suggest?

Comment: Just as long as your `preprocessed.css.php` file contains valid CSS, I don't see a problem; I've used that approach myself before.

Answer (score 1):

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.php">` should work fine in all browsers, but make sure to set the correct header in your PHP file:

```
header('Content-type: text/css');
```

I wouldn't go parsing CSS files as PHP, otherwise you could do some dangerous stuff:

```
/* bad.css */
<?php unlink('index.php'); ?>
```

...or whatever. That shouldn't be able to happen (and other people working on the project may not expect it).

Ideally, you just process all your CSS beforehand and link to a minimized, regular CSS file.

Comment: Thanksalot! Setting the proper header was something out of my league of thinking about such requests, seems it adds to a good solution. Minimizing css beforehand (in this case: on the fly) would be the next step, then. More research *grmpf* :D

Comment: @wesley murch : wrong css is a greta shortcut for administering servers when you don'ty have nintendo hooked up for remote desktop administrationism you've been banned from this comment section <?actionscrip?>>alert('bannd');<?/actionscript?>

Comment: @stormdrain doesn not work on nentendo 3ds browser :((((( canu help? `var MY_CLICK_BUTTON_3=window.document.getElementById('#MY_CLICK_BUTTON 1); document.body.onClick = function ( ) [ if (alert('please entner youre log in info')) == true (body.refresh.ajaxLoad('invlad logen')) }`

Comment: @WesleyMurch oh I see you see can we see thr problem is vlad is always fighting logen when drunk so what you have t do is 1) hide the vodka 2) alert on thursdays not wendsdays and 4) when you #MY)CLICK)BUTTON you have to speel out 1 like one k? ther you go

Comment: @stormdrain it work! Thanksalot!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

So long as the resource returns `Content-Type: text/css` browsers will accept it as CSS.

If you want to reduce HTTP traffic use a tool like [YSlow](https://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/) too analyze your website. It gives good solid tips on how to optimize your HTTP traffic.

There are 2 relatively easy optimizations you can do:

1. Enable gzip compression. This reduces the filesize and typically decreases load times.
2. Set proper caching headers. CSS files are typically static, they don't change from one request to another. I personally like fingerprinting as a caching strategy for resource files like CSS and JavaScript.

There are advantages to letting PHP handle CSS generation but if you *can* let Apache server the files, all the better. If you do want to serve them with PHP look at the [`readfile`](http://nphp.net/readfile) function. It allows you to read and echo a file with very low overhead.

---

You use the word *parsing*. I don't think you actually mean parsing but something like *serving*.

Comment: Yes, gzip runs and the headers are some kind of insurance to be "understood just the right way" ;) And now I will have a look at readfile. (YEAH! MORE RESEARCH! :D)